# Customize error with JSON response from controller in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

I'm using Jquery 3, and Laravel 5.8, and want to customize an error with JSON response from My controller.

I've tried to return response from controller, but it's appear default error message.

```php
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $po = Po::findOrFail($id);
        $po->delete();

        if($po) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Product Owner Deleted',
                'data' => $po
            ]);
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'msg' => 'Failed to delete a product owner / Po is assigned to project'
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Jquery

```
// Delete Data
    $('body').on('click', '#btn-destroy', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        let me = $(this),
            url = me.attr('href'),
            csrf_token = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');

        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure want to delete?',
            text: "Choose Option Wisely",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, Delete it!'
          }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    method: 'POST',
                    data : {
                        '_token': csrf_token,
                        '_method': 'DELETE'
                    },
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        toastr.warning('Deleting Data...', 'WARNING');
                    },
                    success: function(data) {   
                        toastr.success(data.message, 'SUCCESS');
                        $('#datatable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                    },
                    error: function(xhr) {
                        let error = xhr.responseJSON; 
                        toastr.error(error.msg, 'ERROR');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

I want to return error like in condition, if true show this, if false show that. But, it always return error like :

" SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1…`(`id`)) (SQL: delete from`pos`where`id` = 1 "

Comment: how does ur table and model looks like? i would be more specific on selecting record using where $po = Po::where('id', $id)->first();

Comment: @Skeldar

Model 
(http://pasted.co/7f15e4a1]

Migration
http://pasted.co/a654641c

but.. it's still same when I use first().

Comment: @HudaPrasetyo does your table is related to other table with Primary/Foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

change your condition like that.

```
   $po = Po::findOrFail($id);

    if($po->delete()) {
        ...
    } else {
       ...
    }
```

Comment: Hmm.. still same results. It return default error message

Comment: please try this Query Builder like `DB::table('pos')->where('id', $id)->delete();`

Comment: `truncate` the table and do the delete using `implicit` model binding and check the status inside  `ajax` request `success`  function..

Comment: wait... can You explain more spesific, please ?, i didn;t get the point. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
public function addCourse(Request $request)
 {
   $courseData = new Course();
   $courseSaved = $courseData->save();
   if ($courseSaved) {
     return response()->json(
       [
        'status' => 1,
        'message' => 'Course added successfully.'
       ]
     );
    } else {
       return response()->json(
          [
           'status' => 0,
           'message' => 'Something Was Wrong.'
          ]
        );
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Please, insert comments in your answer in order to be clear for all. Thanks.